# Access current Array of object's index with objectArray.length not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

var objArray = [];
var object = {};

I am defining every index of the array by adding :

```
objArray[objArray.length] = object;
```

And I can access the length of the objArray by doing

```
objArray.length;
```

However, if I try to do

```
objArray[objArray.length],
```

it gives me undefined.

Why is this?

Comment: `objArray.length` will have changed, and it's always 1 larger than the largest index. Use `objArray[objArray.length -1]` to get the last item.

Comment: Very true, I had forgotten that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Because indexing of arrays starts with 0, but when there is one element in an array its index is 0 and array length is 1.
Try objArray[objArray.length -1] and it will work.